# Frame by frame animation with Audio using Services in Android

Tags: android, audio, animation, service

I need some help in the concept of Services in Android? Actually i want to Play some sounds with animation in Android. I'm done with frame by frame animation successfully but want to play some audio with animation. I got some ideas about Services from google but I'm unable to get their point, so that i am posting it over here. If anyone has any idea about how can i do this please give me some suggestion to do this. It would be very helpful to me.

Have a nice day ahead...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to take a look at,

[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

I think the documentation given is self-explanatory. Also you need not make use of a separate Service for playing the sounds, unless of course you have a special need.

Comment: Glad it was of help. Seeing that you're new to SO, you should accept an answer, if you deem it so. :)

Comment: Ya i am new to SO, even don't know how to accept it. Bcoz i didn't see any accept button or link,, But i will do it.. Thanks once again